# How to define Input and Output types to a proxy service in WSO2 ESB?

Tags: proxy, wsdl, wso2, wso2-esb

I am trying to create a proxy service which should take a string as an Input and response back a string ( String as an Output ) , In order to do so , I would define inputs and outputs in my XML Schema and I'd create a Proxy Service using the  created XML Schema in Oracle Service Bus.

When it comes to WSO2 ESB , i dont find the functionality of using XML Schema methodology to define input and output for a proxy service

In WSO2 we have an option of defining the Input and Output to a proxy service in the form of WSDL ( Specifically an Abstract WSDL )

I tried to implement the same when creating the Proxy Service from WSo2 ESB console , but it is throwing an error like :- Proxy Service creation Error ; Unbale to find the Service running with the targetnamespace mentioned in the WSDL file .

Could you please help me on this

Answer (score 0):

Following documentation explains about Proxy Services and how to create them.

http://docs.wso2.org/display/ESB480/Lesson+Three%3A+Mediating+Services

http://docs.wso2.org/display/ESB480/Working+with+Proxy+Services

Proxy services have an option called `publishWSDL` for which you can specify a WSDL which would be published as the WSDL of the proxy service and which can be accessed as

`http://localhost:8280/services/NameOfProxy?wsdl`

Not sure what you mean as 'defining input and output'. It would be helpful if you share your proxy service config and the exact error you get.